# Linux- finding files with grep

Tags: bash, shell, grep

I'm new to Linux and I don't really know what I'm doing wrong.
I need to find files in catalog /usr/sbin that have 'fs' in their name and don't start with 'x'.
I need to write results in 111.txt file but cannot use find to do this.
I tried this command but it doesn't work.

```
grep -r -v '^x' -w 'fs' /usr/sbin/ > 111.txt
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could pipe find into two chained grep commands instead:

```
find /usr/sbin/ | grep 'fs' | grep -v '^/usr/sbin/x' > 111.txt
```

Answer (score 2):

`grep` isn't meant for that, you should use `find` instead:

```sh
find /usr/sbin -type f -name '*fs*' -not -name 'x*' > 111.txt
```

Comment: @wyntia, see [What should I do when someone answers my question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers).

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
shopt -s extglob
printf '%s\n' /usr/sbin/@(fs*|[^x]*fs*) >111.txt
```

- `shopt -s extglob` enables "extended globbing", which supports patterns like `@(pattern1|pattern2)`.  See the [extglob](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/glob#extglob) section in [glob - Greg's Wiki](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/glob).
- This answer originally suggested

  ```
    # BAD CODE.  DON'T USE.
    printf '%s\n' /usr/sbin/[^x]*fs* >111.txt
  ```

  That was broken because it excludes files whose names begin with `fs`.

Comment: With this pattern, `fs.txt` is not included. Not sure if it's what OP intended.

Comment: @Philippe, thanks for pointing out the bug.  I should have been more careful.